# Pass value in laravel Model object

Tags: php, laravel

I have a package code like:

```
$rajaongkir = new Rajaongkir\Domestic(YOUR_API_KEY, Rajaongkir\Domestic::ACCOUNT_PRO);
```

and my code is like:

```
$rajakey = Rajaongkir::all();
foreach($rajakey as $raj){
  $key = $raj->key;
  $type = $raj->type;
}
```

I can replace `YOUR_API_KEY` with `$key` with ease but my problem is second part of this code `Rajaongkir\Domestic::ACCOUNT_PRO` this `ACCOUNT_PRO` should be replaced by `$type` but i keep getting this error:

```
Access to undeclared static property: Ncaneldiee\Rajaongkir\Domestic::$type
```

This is how it's look when I get that error:

```
$rajaongkir = new Raja\Domestic($key, Raja\Domestic::$type);
```

My question is:

**How to pass `$type` in my code to avoid that error?**

Comment: can you also post your Domestic class

Comment: @MilanMaharjan this is the packages https://github.com/ncaneldiee/rajaongkir/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the wrong way to access the variable `Domestic::$type`

If you want to change your type dynamically then do like this,

```
$type = Rajaongkir\Domestic::ACCOUNT_PRO
```

Pass the `$type` variable to object

```
$rajaongkir = new Raja\Domestic($key, $type);
```

Comment: but the issue is `account_pro` has to change otherwise it doesn't make difference

Comment: I used only second part of your answer and it's working `$rajaongkir = new Raja\Domestic($key, $type);` thanks

Answer (score 0):

This `type` statement is probably a string it's define the type of your account you have to use like this

```
 $rajaongkir = new Raja\Domesti('API_KEY', Domestic::ACCOUNT_PRO);
```

OR

```
$type = Domestic::ACCOUNT_PRO;
```

OR

```
$type = 'pro'; // see the doc for more information
```

Later

```
 $rajaongkir = new Raja\Domesti('API_KEY', $type);
```